# How to make a window.onload event fire without reloading the page javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am wondering if it is possible to cause a window.onload event to occur without reloading the page. I want to use this becuase I am using ajax to load new pages, however this ajax load method doesn't make the window.onload event fire.

Right now I am using:

```
location.reload();
```

But this causes the whole page to reload.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are trying to save/keep state of any variable/function in javascript which you do not want to burn on reload. Just keep that in cookies and check on reload.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the purpose here, but let's assume you have this:

```
window.onload = function() {...};
```

You could do this instead:

```
var bootstrap = function() {...}
window.onload = bootstrap;
```

then in other part of your code, where you want to simulate the `onload`, just 
call `bootstrap` function by yourself.

Comment: the problem is, I have a ton of different functions to call.

Comment: Well then, it's a question of code organization. The easiest would be to have `bootstrap` call a lot of functions and you re-use them as necessary.

I would, however, suggest, if you have a large codebase, to look into AMD loader, I use http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Inside your call back function you might say,

```
window.location.href = 'correctpath_here';
```

Or

```
window.location.reload = true;
```